# How to fill in a binary file with a hex value in vim?

Tags: vim

As in subject.

I'd like to fill in a part of the binary file (base address + offset) in vim with a value given.

For example I'd like to add 1M values of `0xfd` starting from address `0x0fff`.

What command could I use?

Comment: why in vim? vim is a text editor and isn't very friendly towards binary file formats.

Comment: because I use gvim...?

Comment: You might be better off looking at something like khexedit that is a dedicated hex editor, but if you insist on using vim look here http://usevim.com/2012/06/20/vim-binary-files/

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the file in *binary mode*, either via `vim -b {filespec}` or via `:edit ++bin {filespec}`.
2. Go to byte index `0x0fff` with the `go` command or `:goto`. You need to convert to decimal, e.g.: `:exe 'goto' 0x0fff`.
3. Insert the value; you can supply a `[count]` to the `i` command, and insert arbitrary hex values via `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`: `1048576i<C-V>xfd<Esc>`
4. Write the file and exit `:wq`.

An alternative within Vim is using an intermediate *hex dump* format and converting back and forth via the `xxd` tool that ships with Vim. See [Improved hex editing](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_hex_editing) for details.

So, while Vim isn't the perfect tool for this (as mentioned in the comments, a hex editor is the right / better tool), it can be done.